# Getting Error while updating data grid view using adapter in vb.net windows form application

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have populated a DataGridView from the two tables.i am working on windows forms

In page load event I have this code:

```
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim bSource As BindingSource
Dim dt1 As DataTable

     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SUPPORT2\SUPPORT2;Initial Catalog=Registry;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=solutions") 'SET THE CONNECTION STRING
            con.Open()

            Dim cd As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select c.cid,c.CompanyName,d.dtName,d.dtPhone,d.dtEmail  from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId", con)
            dt1 = New DataTable
            bSource = New BindingSource
            adapter.Fill(dt1)
            bSource.DataSource = dt1
            gv.DataSource = bSource
        End Sub
```

in update button click i given code like this:

```
Dim cid As Integer
        Dim cmpname As String
        Dim dtname As String
        Dim dtPhone As String
        Dim dtEmail As String
 Dim rv = DirectCast(bSource.Current, DataRowView)
        cid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Cid")
        cmpname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("CompanyName")
        dtname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("dtName")
        dtPhone = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("dtPhone")
        dtEmail = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("dtEmail")

        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cmpname)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtName", dtname)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtPhone", dtPhone)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEmail", dtEmail)
        adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = @CompanyName, dtName = @dtName, dtPhone = @dtPhone, dtEmail = @dtEmail WHERE Cid = @Cid", con)
```

Whenever I edit something in the dataGridView and click update button i am getting error in this line: **adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid)**
Error: *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Comment: check your **SELECT Statement** your not selecting **C.ID**..

Answer (score 0):

I think you Need to reinitialize you adapter , add this to your button click code :

```
    Adapter =  new SqlDataAdapter
```

**EDIT :**
Change Your Code Like This :

```
    adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = @CompanyName, dtName = @dtName, dtPhone = @dtPhone, dtEmail = @dtEmail WHERE Cid = @Cid", con)
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid)
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cmpname)
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtName", dtname)
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtPhone", dtPhone)
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEmail", dtEmail)
    adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: now not getting any error..this should update in database also right?

Comment: with this code not updating anything in database,,i think we forget to add some code

Comment: so i dont want to add adapter.Update(dt1)?

Comment: it s oke sir,,actually i am updating two tables,,so i have write two separate query right??

Comment: yes you have write two separate query, if this answer work for you please mark as answer.

Comment: i wrote two separate query,,the same time i updated 3 rows,,but this code is effecting last update row,,what is missing in this code?

Comment: because in your code you only take the last row you need to loop throw all row and update it

Comment: how to loop throw all row,,

Comment: sir i given the entire code inside the loop like this:               For Each row As DataGridViewRow In gv.Rows
    'my code here
Next